# Background color doesn't fill in horizontal scrolling dropdown item

Tags: html, css, user-interface, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am working on a UI for a project. I am using bootstrap to create the UI.

I have a dropdown that holds the history of previous searches. Since these searches can be very long, the dropdown can get long enough that it is cut off by the edge of the page. To fix this, I set the max width to be a percentage of the page width, and then let the user horizontally scroll if there is overflow. This works well, but there is a bug where the background color does not stretch horizontally to fill a long element.

I have searched for this problem and there appears to be a consistent problem in my case. This UI is going to be prone to resizing, ranging anywhere from like 150 px in width all the way to a full browser, so the size of both the page and the dropdown will not be static.

I extracted the relevant page and code and put it into bootply. I also put the css I consider relevant at the top of the css file. The problematic dropdown is the one with the clock icon. Click on it, and the dropdown is dark colored. Scroll over, and the longest item will lose its background color. I want the entire dropdown element to be the same bg color.

Note that the ultimate width of this element is much larger than the width that I had to limit the dropdown to, and I do not know this ultimate width.

Here is the bootply: https://www.bootply.com/2J0SOnElvM

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

> CSS

```
.dropdown-menu {
  max-height: 12.5em; /* 5 elements with 2.5em height */
  overflow-y: auto;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;

  background-color: green; /* Your Background Color */

}
```

Comment: Thanks, that fixes the background issue. However, there is a subsequent issue for the hover. I want the background color to change when hovering over a dropdown element, which works. But the background color change does not stretch all the way across for the long dropdown element. Do you know how to fix that?